# Repeated pattern in XMLElement

Tags: pattern-matching, xml

I have an XML file like this:

```
xml = XMLObject["Document"][
  XMLElement[
   "whatever", {}, {
     {XMLElement["forename", {"type" -> "first"}, {"Adrian"}], 
      XMLElement["surname", {}, {"Adgar"}]
    },
    {XMLElement["forename", {"type" -> "first"}, {"Babar"}], 
     XMLElement["forename", {"type" -> "middle"}, {"Barbados"}], 
     XMLElement["surname", {}, {"Bode"}]
    }, 
    {XMLElement["forename", {"type" -> "first"}, {"Charly"}], 
     XMLElement["surname", {}, {"Chimp"}]
    }
}]]
```

I'd like to extract the first names, middle names if any, and surnames.

Using repeated patterns, I would have expected this to work:

```
Cases[xml, {(XMLElement["forename", _, x_])..., 
      XMLElement["surname", {}, y_]} -> {x, y}, Infinity]
(* {{{"Adrian"}, {"Adgar"}}, {{"Charly"}, {"Chimp"}}} *)
```

however it misses the middle names. Instead, I would like an output like:

```
{{"Adrian", "Adgar"}, {"Babar", "Barbados", "Bode"}, {"Charly", "Chimp"}}
```

I am also wondering what is wrong in this syntax.

Answer (score 4):

```
Cases[xml,XMLElement["forename" | "surname", _, x_] :> x, \[Infinity]]

(*
{{"Adrian"}, {"Adgar"}, {"Babar"}, {"Barbados"}, {"Bode"}, \
{"Charly"}, {"Chimp"}}
*)
```

**Edit**

Looks like we have to guess at what the desired output is so here is guess #2 with first names and surnames grouped. In the example provided first names always precede surnames in the grouping therefore the solution is based on that fact.

```
Cases[xml, x : {__XMLElement} :> Flatten[x[[All, -1]]], {3}]
(*
{{"Adrian", "Adgar"}, {"Babar", "Barbados", "Bode"}, {"Charly", 
  "Chimp"}}

*)
```

Comment: The problem with that is I don't know if "Adgar" is the middle name of Mr. Babar, or if it's Mr. Adgar.

Comment: @anderstood you need to make it clear in the question what you are seeking. Why not give the output you are after rather than make people guess?

Answer (score 3):

A minimal example showing why the original `Cases` doesn't work,

```
data = {{f[1], g[2]}, {f[1], f[2], g[3]}, {f[1], f[1], g[3]}};

Cases[
 data,
 {(f[x_] ..), g[y_]}
 ]
(* {{f[1], g[2]}, {f[1], f[1], g[3]}} *)

Cases[
 data,
 {(f[_] ..), g[y_]}
 ]
(* {{f[1], g[2]}, {f[1], f[2], g[3]}, {f[1], f[1], g[3]}} *)
```

Using a named pattern alongside `Repeated` means that the elements that match that named pattern need to be the same.  So `{f[1], f[2], g[3]}` matches `{(f[_] ..), g[y_]}` but not `{(f[x_] ..), g[y_]}`.

This loses some brevity, but when in doubt I like to spell my patterns out explicitly.

```
forenamePattern = XMLElement["forename", _, _];
surnamePattern = XMLElement["surname", _, _];
namePattern = {forenamePattern .., surnamePattern};
getNamesFromPattern = 
  ReplaceAll[x : (forenamePattern | surnamePattern) :> Last@x];
Cases[xml, name : namePattern :> getNamesFromPattern[name], Infinity]
(* {{{"Adrian"}, {"Adgar"}}, {{"Babar"}, {"Barbados"}, \
{"Bode"}}, {{"Charly"}, {"Chimp"}}} *)
```